# Chrome develop tool can´t seem to find the background color

Tags: css, wordpress, google-chrome, woocommerce, google-chrome-devtools

I use Chrome development tools to inspect a header color I want to change:

[image: Chrome development tools]

I have located it, and I can change it in the inspector view, but I want to change it for real, so I need to know where the CSS is … but it says that it is a index file (index) 573.

What does this mean?

It is a wordpress theme and more specifically it is the woocommerce  plugin

Comment: when you see `(index)`: That mean that this styles are directly injected on the page source code… As this style use `!important`, is going to be very hard to override it. This is surely a setting in your theme or in a plugin…

Answer (score 0):

You can try overriding in style sheet using more descriptors in CSS.
Maybe something like:

```
html body .woocommerce-page form table.shop_table thead {
  background-color: #333333 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could click where it's indexed in the Element inspector to bring up the CSS file. It's probably min'd so I'd recommend using PrettyPrint. That should show you, unless I misunderstood.

Here's a screen shot album I put together. I have Devtools Author so ignore the silly UI https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmojS.jpg